# Proof Verification - Elementary proof that $\sqrt3$ is irrational

Tags: proof-verification, radicals, irrational-numbers

Sorry for the dumb question; something about this proof seems off and I was wondering what (if anything) is wrong with it.

Assume $p$, $q$ are integers. We prove by contradiction.

$\sqrt3 = p/q$

$(\sqrt3)^3 = (p/q)^3$

$3 = p^3/q^3$

$3q^3 = p^3$

$\sqrt[3]{3q^3} = \sqrt[3]{p^3}$

$3q = p$

Then we substitute into the original equation:

$\sqrt 3 = 3q/q$

$\sqrt 3 = 3$

But it $3\cdot 3$ is clearly not $3$; so we have a contradiction.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: $(\sqrt{3})^3$ is not equal to $3$.

Comment: You mix up cube-roots and square-roots. Which do you intend?

Comment: The cuberoot of 3 is not 3 either.

Comment: Also, you never used that $p$ and $q$ are integers. In fact, you "showed" that $\sqrt{3}$ is not a number.

Comment: Can you clarify whether what you wrote is what you meant? As well as helping answerers it will mean someone can format the maths for you if you're not sure how to do that yet.

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{3q^3} \ne 3q$.  It equals $\sqrt[3]{3} q$ which... gets us going in circles.

Comment: Klaus has a good point.  Your proof is essentially $\sqrt 3= x$.  So $(\sqrt 3)^3 = x^3$ so $3 = x^3$ so $\sqrt[3]{3}= \sqrt[3]{x^3}$ so $3 = x$.  So pluggin in to original $\sqrt 3 = 3$ which is clearly false.  So $\sqrt 3$ can't exist. (The problem of course are $(\sqrt 3)^3 \ne 3$ and $\sqrt[3]{3} \ne 3$.)

Comment: Just a nitpick.  When you say "Assume $p,q$ are integers" you can't then say $\sqrt 3 = \frac pq$ because if $p$ and $q$ are any integers we have no idea what $\frac pq$ is.  Instead so "Assume that $p,q$ are integers where $\sqrt 3 = \frac pq$."  But that's a nitpick.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone; I’m doubly sorry that I can’t format it since I obviously got very confused with my surds.

Comment: Nevertheless, I still (mistakenly?) think there’s a proof. By SQUARING sqrt(3) and (p/q) and manipulating, we get to 3q^2 = p^2. Taking the square root of both sides gives 3q = p, and then continue as above. Why wouldn’t this be correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I think I understand now having read Fleablood’s answer. Even making the above changes, I clearly went wrong in saying that sqrt(3q^2) = 3q; as you rightly say, it’s equal to sqrt(3)•q. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you meant $\sqrt{3}$ or $\sqrt[3]{3}$.  As $(\sqrt{3})^3 \ne 3$ your proof is off to a wrong start. And then when you take the the cube root latter you essentially undo it ... exept you don't.  You argument uses $(\sqrt 3)^3 = 3$ (wrong) and $\sqrt[3]{3} = 3$ (very wrong) and so $\sqrt 3 = 3$ (wrong).  In actuality you would have done either $(\sqrt 3)^2=3$ and $\sqrt{3} = \sqrt {3}$ so $\sqrt 3 = \sqrt 3$ (true but useless) or $(\sqrt[3] 3)^3 = 3$ and $\sqrt[3]{3} = \sqrt[3]{3} $ so $\sqrt[3] 3= \sqrt[3] 3$ (ditto).

Your proof should mirror the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

$\color{blue}{\text { Assume }\sqrt 2 = \frac ab\text{ where }a,b\text{ are integers with no common factors}}$

Okay so Assume $\sqrt 3 = \frac pq$ where $p,q$ are integers with no common factors.

$\color{blue}{2 = \frac {a^2}{b^2}\\ 2b^2 = a^2\\ \text {so }2\text{ divides }a^2}$

Okay... so

$3 =\frac {p^2}{q^2}\\ 3q^2 = p^2\\$
So $3$ divides $p^2$.

$\color{blue}{\text{Either }a\text{ is odd or }a\text{ is even.}\\\text{If }a\text{ is odd, then }a^2\text{ is odd, which is a contradiction.}\\\text{So }a\text{ is even.}}$

Okay... this is where $3$ is slightly different than $2$.

Either $p$ is divisible by $3$ or $p$ has remainder $1$ or $2$ when divided by $p$.

If $p$ has remainder $1$ then $p = 3k+1$ for some integer $k$ and $p^2 = (3k+1)^2 = 3k^2 + 6k + 1$ is not divisible by $3$.  If $p$ has remainder $2$ then $p = 3k + 2$ for some integer $k$ and $p^2 = (3k + 2)^2 = 3k^2 + 12k + 4$ is not divisible by $3$.  Those are contradictions so $p$ is divisible by $3$ is the only option.

$\color{blue}{\text{So }a = 2k\text{ for some integer }k\text{ and }2b^2 = a^2 = (2k)^2 = 4k^2\text{.}\\\text  {So }b^2 = 2k^2}$.

So $q= 3k$ for some integer $k$ and $3p^2 = q^2 = (3q)^2=9q^2$ and $p^2 = 3q^2$.

$\color{blue}{\text{So }b^2\text{ is even and by the exact same argument, }b\text{ is even. }}$

So $p^2$ is divisible by $3$ and by the exact same argument $p$ is divisible by $3$.

$\color{blue}{\text{So both }a\text{ and }b\text{ are even and have factors of }2\text{. }\\\text{But that's a contradiction.}}$

So both $p$ and $q$ are divisible by $3$.  But that's a contradiction.

Comment: I did indeed come to this by trying to adapt the proof that sqrt(2) is irrational. I mistakenly thought I could get a contradiction that didn’t involve appealingly to the oddness or evenness of p and q: but I can’t, and it’s it even clear what such a proof would look like.

Comment: Well, since you are dealing with 3 and not 2 the oddness or evenness of $p,q$ won't be relevent.  It's the divisibility be $3$ that would matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is incorrect. You've mixed up cube roots and square roots; in fact, it's hard to ascertain what you have done. $\sqrt{3}^3$ is certainly not equal to $3$, and then you simply took the cube root of that, which would make the statement $\sqrt{3}q=p$. I would recommend you to read up on surds again.

The correct proof would be a derivative of the proof that the square root of $2$ is irrational.

Here's how:

Let $\sqrt3 = \frac{p}{q}$, where $\gcd(p,q)=1$, and $p,q\in \Bbb N$.

Thus $3=\frac{p^2}{q^2} \Rightarrow 3p^2=q^2$, which implies that $3|q$. Why is this true? I urge you to try it out on some numbers yourself: if a prime divides the product of two numbers, it must divide the numbers themselves. This is known as *Euclid's Lemma*. Here, the two numbers are $q$ and $q$. They multiply together to form $q^2$, and thus since $p$ cannot possibly divide $q$, we are left with $3$ dividing $q$.

Again, let $q=3a \Rightarrow p^2=9a^2$, which implies that $3|p$ (Why?) contradicting the fact that they are relatively prime. This proves that our assumption was wrong, and $\sqrt{3}$ cannot possibly be written as a rational.

Comment: Wow, we can *differentiate* irrationality proofs! No doubt this implies there is a sicker proof via l'Hospital.

Comment: Haha. Good one.

Comment: Might need to explain why $3|q^2$ would imply $3|q$....  It's almost certain that the OP hasn't proven Euclid's Lemma yet.

Comment: @fleablood Done.

Comment: Thank you Naman for the suggestion: as I say above, the cube-roots and raising things to the third power were just typos: but I made some others silly errors with surds and in any case a proof that tries for contradiction without considering the GFC of p and q will just prove the impossibility of writing root-3 as a quotient of ANY two numbers (which just means it doesn’t exist)! Thanks again.